# Is there any good way to display products on sliding banner(Home page) in Magento ver 1.6.2.0

Tags: magento

Is there any good way to display products on sliding banner in Magento ver 1.6.2.0 ?

I tried but I am facing two problems:

1. JavaScript conflicts (I used `jquery.min.js` for banner then after adding to cart, is not working)
2. I created new attributes for product image but I'm unable to call it on sliding banner.

Answer (score 0):

Try the avalnache theme .

http://fastdivision.com/themes/avalanche/?utm_source=fastdivision.com&utm_medium=blog&utm_content=top-menu&utm_campaign=avalanche

Some really cool features in it.

[image]

You can custmise it futher, but is a good starting point.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

create a CMS static block, set his identifier as '**home_slideshow**', and paste in it's content:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    start_slideshow(1, 3, 3000);
    function start_slideshow(start_frame, end_frame, delay) {
        id = setTimeout(switch_slides(start_frame,start_frame,end_frame, delay), delay);
    }
    function switch_slides(frame, start_frame, end_frame, delay) {
        return (function() {
            Effect.Fade('slide' + frame, { duration: 1.0 });
            if (frame == end_frame) { frame = start_frame; } else { frame = frame + 1; }
            Effect.Appear('slide' + frame, { duration: 1.0 });
            if (delay == 1000) { delay = 3000; }
            id = setTimeout(switch_slides(frame, start_frame, end_frame, delay), delay);
        })
    }
    function stop_slideshow() {
        clearTimeout(id);
    }
</script>
<div id="slideshowhomepage" style="height: 230px; position: relative;" onmouseover="stop_slideshow()" onmouseout="start_slideshow(1, 3, 1000)">
    <div id="slide1" class="slide" style="position: absolute; top: 0pt; left: 0pt; display: block; z-index: 3; opacity: 1;"><a href="{{store direct_url='webpage1.html'}}"><img src="{{skin url='path/to/image1.jpg'}}" border="0" alt="" /></a></div>
    <div id="slide2" class="slide" style="position: absolute; top: 0pt; left: 0pt; display: none; z-index: 2; opacity: 0;"><a href="{{store direct_url='webpage2.html'}}"><img src="{{skin url='path/to/image2.jpg'}}" border="0" alt="" /></a></div>
    <div id="slide3" class="slide" style="position: absolute; top: 0pt; left: 0pt; display: none; z-index: 1; opacity: 0;"><a href="{{store direct_url='webpage3.html'}}"><img src="{{skin url='path/to/image3.jpg'}}" border="0" alt="" /></a></div>
</div>
```

then edit you're home CMS page and add this block:

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="home_slideshow" template="cms/content.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nivo Slider (one the most awesome jquery slider) for sliding banner.

If you want  an easy way, just creating new group for homepage slider and adding images/slides  to it then you can try the following extension for Magento:
http://www.magepsycho.com/jquery-sliders-pro-nivo-slider.html

You just need to add following code in your cms page:

```
{{block type="jquerysliderspro/slider" identifier="group-identifier-for-homepage-slider"}}
```

In fact you can use unlimited no of sliders anywhere in frontend.

Cheers